# How to Add Links to Magento Default Footer

Tags: magento, footer, magento-1.9

I've reviewed several tutorials on creating your own custom footer in Magento but none relating to adding links to the default footer. I am wanting to add a few links under the "Account" div of the Magento default footer. Here's what I have in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title before_text" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><li/><a/></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer_links2">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /><title>My Account</title></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Customer Service</label><url helper="/customer-service/" /><title>Customer Service</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for add link in footer.your code is almost right but you made mistake in reference name make you sure that reference name `footer_links`

```
<reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /><title>My Account</title></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Customer Service</label><url helper="/customer-service/" /><title>Customer Service</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it didn't work. The reference name `footer_links2` was the default reference name. Nothing was changed. However, I tried both `footer_links` and `footer_links2` with your suggested code and neither worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you check default link coming from xml or static block.

Comment: It's coming from an .xml. I tried changing the static block first and nothing happened and it doesn't show the "My Account" or "Orders and Returns" links.